# `who am i` after `su` not showing new user id?

Tags: su, whoami

Why is it that when I switch user `su <username>` and then execute `who am i` is outputs the previous user which I was logged as and not the one I've switched to?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're likely running the wrong command.

- `who` is meant to show who is logged in, i.e. which user owns the terminal.
  It returns a line like this:

  ```
  ckhan    pts/1        2012-11-05 03:06 (c-21-13-25-10.ddw.ca.isp.net)
  ```
- `whoami` is mean to show you what the effective user id is of the person running it.
  It returns just a single name, like this (and is equivalent to running `id -un`):

  ```
  ckhan
  ```

I think you may have literally typed `who am i` at the terminal, which ran `who` with two ignored arguments (`am`, `i`).

See `man who` and `man whoami` for more details.

Comment: The two arguments `am` and `i` are not ignored, they are even specified by POSIX: "In  the POSIX locale, limit the output to describing the invoking user, equivalent to the `-m` option."

Comment: Accidentally downvoted, wouldn't let me change my vote.

Answer (score 6):

**Workaround**:

```
ls -l `tty` | awk '{print $3}'
```

that works as replacement from `who am i | awk '{print $1}'` . Explanation below:

On many systems "`who am i`" is equivalent to "`who -m`". 
The problem here is that with some *terminals*, "`who -m`" returns nothing!

Example #1 run from a xfce4-terminal

```
Pegasus ~ # whoami
root
Pegasus ~ # who am i
thomas   pts/1        2017-08-19 11:15 (:0.0)
Pegasus ~ # who -m
thomas   pts/1        2017-08-19 11:15 (:0.0)
Pegasus ~ # who
thomas   tty8         2017-08-19 10:18 (:0)
thomas   pts/1        2017-08-19 11:15 (:0.0)
thomas   pts/5        2017-08-19 16:16 (:0.0)
Pegasus ~ # who am i | awk '{print $1}'
thomas
Pegasus ~ #
```

but
Example #2 from a gnome-terminal (same computer, same commands)

```
Pegasus ~ # whoami
root
Pegasus ~ # who am i
Pegasus ~ # who -m
Pegasus ~ # who
thomas   tty8         2017-08-19 10:18 (:0)
thomas   pts/1        2017-08-19 11:15 (:0.0)
thomas   pts/5        2017-08-19 16:16 (:0.0)
Pegasus ~ #
```

This seems to be a consequence of gnome-terminal not adding utmp entries…

Comment: [Don't parse ls!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Use `stat` instead: `stat -c '%U' "$(tty)"` You probably shouldn't parse `who am i` either, since usernames can contain spaces in some rare cases.

Answer (score 5):

Per my Ubuntu 12.04.2 man page for the 'who' command, 'who am i' (or who with any two arguments) is the same as 'who -m' and should give you the hostname and user associated with STDIN.  However I get no output with 'who am i'.  Either the man page is wrong or the command has a bug.  Regardless, as previously answered by ckhan, the 'whoami' command will give you the username for your effective user ID.  At least in Ubuntu 12.04.2, none of id, 'who am i', or 'whoami' will give you just the username of the person logged in on the current terminal.  As a workaround you could get that with:

```
who | sed 's/ .*//'
```

Comment: Note that this is Linux specific. This returns the original username in Unix / SunOS.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the user shell was `/bin/false` in /etc/passwd which is why su didn't return an error. In other words, `su somebody` failed with no error and I was still root, not somebody.

The solution was `su somebody -s /bin/bash` or whatever shell you want. And then obviously `whoami` works as expected.